# What's the most efficient way to calculate frequency of each letter in a string C++?

Tags: c++, string

I was asked to do a task to count for each letter in the string how many times it occurs in it. It's assumed that all characters are alphabetical lower-case English letters. Also I should output string letters in ascending order, along with the frequency of each. I've tried to do so using `std::set` like the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    int cnt[26] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        cnt[s[i] - 'a']++;
    }
    std::set <char> st;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        st.insert(s[i]);
    }
    for (auto x : st) {
        std::cout << x << " : " << cnt[x - 'a'] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's actually your question?  This forum works much better for you if you have a _problem_ that you completely spell out.  See [mcve].

Comment: @davidbak It's on the question title.

Comment: I doubt there is anything much more efficient than the way you are doing it.  Are you guaranteed that all the chars in your input string will be between 'a' and 'z', though?  Because if any are not, your first for-loop is going to end up writing to an out-of-bounds array index and invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Edited, It's assumed in the problem statement that all characters would be from 'a' through 'z'

Comment: "Also I should output string letters in ascending order with its frequency", means print letters from those with most occurances to those with less or just from a to z ?

Comment: @user3655463 From a to z each with its frequency, Excuse my English, for example consider input : `regff` output should be : 
e : 1
f : 2
g : 1
r : 1

Comment: @AnthonyWatson On the English: This is what "in ascending order with its frequency" does most likely mean, though it's reasonable to wonder if you actually meant "in ascending order by frequency", which would be different.  Or writing "in ascending order, along with the frequency of each" would be a bit clearer that you meant what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit `std::set` and just write like so

```
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    int cnt[26] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        cnt[s[i] - 'a']++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) 
        if (cnt[i] > 0)
            std::cout << (char)('a' + i) << " : " << cnt[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Instead saving in the `std::set`, we check the presence of a character in the `cnt` and to output if a symbol was.
This option takes less memory.

Comment: "It's assumed that all characters are alphabetical English letters". This works only for lower case.

Comment: It is restriction in the question by author

Comment: No, the author wrote: "It's assumed that all characters are alphabetical English letters". Capital letters are also alphabetical.

Comment: Author exact wrote in the last comment: 
_@JeremyFriesner Edited, It's assumed in the problem statement that all characters would be from 'a' through 'z' – Anthony Watson_

Comment: Does it also take less time?

Comment: But it does not sort the frequencies though !!

Comment: @AnthonyWatson I would guess it takes less time, mainly because you avoid the dynamic allocations `std::set` would use. But with any question of optimization, the only answer is to try both programs several times on the actual computer hardware that matters and with a variety of "typical" input sets.

Comment: @AnthonyWatson to know if it take less time you should measure with optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You could have used std::map, something like:

```
std::map<char, int> mymap;
for  (auto &c: s){
    mymap [c]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
bool sortbysec(const pair<int,int> &a,const pair<int,int> &b)
{
   return (a.second < b.second);
}
int main(){
   int len,cntS[26]={0},nonZero=0;
   string s;
   vector< pair<char,int> >v;
   cin>>s;
   len=s.length();
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
      cntS[s[i]-'a']++;
   }
   for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
      if(cntS[i]!=0){
        nonZero++;
        v.push_back(make_pair(char(i+'a'),cntS[i]));
      }
   }
   // Using sort() function to sort by 2nd element
  // of pair
  sort(v.begin(), v.end(), sortbysec);
  for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
      cout<<v[i].first<<v[i].second<<" ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The above code sorts the frequency and then prints it

Comment: Which is not what is asked for, but whatever.

Comment: Finding the frequency of each letter in the string and printing the frequency in ascending order right?.Please correct me

Comment: printing the letters in ascending order with their frequency

Comment: This is wrong code, information about letter itself is lost

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux is it ok now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to store `key -> no occurances`, then move that pairs to vector and sort, the code below:

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> getSortedChars(std::string const& input) {
        std::map<char, int> m;
        std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> vp;
        for (char c : input) {
                ++m[c];
        }
        for (auto e : m) {
                vp.emplace_back(std::move(e));
        }
        std::sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(), [=](std::pair<char, int>& l, std::pair<char, int>& r) {
                return l.second < r.second;});
        return vp;
}
```

The returned vector will have sorted pairs, then you can just print them.